# Sympy solve() gives wrong results

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I use Sympy solve() function to solve a large number of equations. All variables in the equations are defined as symbols. Variables can start with the letter P or F. I use solve() to express one specific P variable (the one that I observe) with only F variables, so I use solve() to substitute all other P variables with F variables. The sum of the coefficients before the F variables is ideally 1 or almost 1 (e.g.: 0.99).

This produces good results till a certain point where the number of equations becomes pretty big and also their length. There the Sympy solve() function starts to give me wrong results. The sum of the coefficients becomes negative (e.g. -7,...). It looks like that the solve() function gets problems with substituting any carrying over all variables and their coefficients.

Is there a way to correct this problem?

Dictionary of equations under link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VBQucrDU-o1diCd6i4rR3MlRh95qycmK

```
    import json
    from sympy import Symbol, Add, Eq, solve


    # Get data

    # data from link above
    with open("C:\\\\Test\\dict.json") as f:
        equations = json.load(f)

    comp =[]
    expressions = []

    for p, equation_components in equations.items():
        p = Symbol(p)
        comp.append(p)
        expression = []
        for name, multiplier in equation_components.items():
            if type(multiplier) == float or type(multiplier) == int: 
                expression.append(Symbol(name) * multiplier)
            else:
                expression.append(Symbol(name) * Symbol(multiplier))
        expressions.append(Eq(p, Add(*expression)))


    # Solution for variable P137807


    print("Solving...")

    # Works for slice :364 !!!!!
    solutions = solve(expressions[:364], comp[:364], simplify=False, rational=False)

    # Gives wrong results for slice :366 and above !!!!!
    # solutions = solve(expressions[:366], comp[:366], simplify=False, rational=False)

    vm_symbol = Symbol("P137807")

    solution_1 = solutions[vm_symbol]

    print("\n")
    print("Solution_1:")
    print(solution_1)
    print("\n")



    #Sum of coefficients

    list_sum = []


    for i in solution_1.args:
        if str(i.args[1]) != "ANaN":
            list_sum.append(i.args[0])
    coeff_sum = sum(list_sum)

    print("Sum:")
    print(coeff_sum)


...
```

Comment: Without a working minimal sample, it might be difficult to help you. However, it seems your might run into numerical instability in the solver because of the number of very small coefficients. playing around with solve precision ('prec') might be of help [link](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html?highlight=prec)

Comment: Hello, I have now provided a working sample. Please check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to mark the problem as solved and provide reference to the solution. [Please look at numerical instability when solving n=385 linear equations with Float coefficients #17136](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17136).

The solution that worked for me was to use the following solver and not the Sympy solve() function:

```
def ssolve(eqs, syms):
    """return the solution of linear system of equations
    with symbolic coefficients and a unique solution.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> eqs=[x-1,x+2*y-z-2,x+z+w-6,2*y+z+x-2]
    >>> v=[x,y,z,w]
    >>> ssolve(eqs, v)
    {x: 1, z: 0, w: 5, y: 1/2}
    """
    from sympy.solvers.solveset import linear_coeffs
    v = list(syms)
    N = len(v)
    # convert equations to coefficient dictionaries
    print('checking linearity')
    d = []
    v0 = v + [0]
    for e in [i.rewrite(Add) for i in eqs]:
        co = linear_coeffs(e, *v)
        di = dict([(i, c) for i, c in zip(v0, co) if c or not i])
        d.append(di)
    print('forward solving')
    sol = {}
    impl = {}
    done = False
    while not done:
        # check for those that are done
        more = set([i for i, di in enumerate(d) if len(di) == 2])
        did = 0
        while more:
            di = d[more.pop()]
            c = di.pop(0)
            x = list(di)[0]
            a = di.pop(x)
            K = sol[x] = -c/a
            v.remove(x)
            changed = True
            did += 1
            # update everyone else
            for j, dj in enumerate(d):
                if x not in dj:
                    continue
                dj[0] += dj.pop(x)*K
                if len(dj) == 2:
                    more.add(j)
        if did: print('found',did,'definitions')
        # solve implicitly for the next variable
        dcan = [i for i in d if len(i) > 2]
        if not dcan:
            done = True
        else:
            # take shortest first
            di = next(ordered(dcan, lambda i: len(i)))
            done = False
            x = next(ordered(i for i in di if i))
            c = di.pop(x)
            for k in di:
                di[k] /= -c
            impl[x] = di.copy()
            di.clear()
            v.remove(x)
            # update everyone else
            for j, dj in enumerate(d):
                if x not in dj:
                    continue
                done = False
                c = dj.pop(x)
                for k in impl[x]:
                    dj[k] = dj.get(k, 0) + impl[x][k]*c
    have = set(sol)
    sol[0] = 1
    while N - len(have):
        print(N - len(have), 'to backsub')
        for k in impl:
            if impl[k] and not set(impl[k]) - have - {0}:
                sol[k] = sum(impl[k][vi]*sol[vi] for vi in impl[k])
                impl[k].clear()
                have.add(k)
    sol.pop(0)
    return sol
```